# result not getting in to the field

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here i have three fields and while adding values in to two fields the sum of that value should enter in to the third field but here the sum function is not getting
here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

    var balanceamount = $("#balance").val();
    var actual_amount = $("#total_amount").val();
    var total_balance = $("#totalbalance").val();

      $("#amount").keyup(function ()
       {
         var amount = $("#amount").val();
         var total_balance = $("#totalbalance").val();
         var total_amount = total_balance + amount;
         alert(total_amount);
         $("#total_amount").val(total_amount.toFixed(2));

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ok so whats the `codeigniter` tag doing here?

Comment: please add your html also for better understanding. also you declare variable with same name `actual_amount` & `total_balance`  twice why?

Comment: Do you have at least concatenated values or nothing? If you have concatenated values, it means that your variables are strings and you have to convert them to integers using the javascript function parseInt() ([JavaScript parseInt() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp))

Comment: try to parse total_balance  and amount into int and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `parseFloat()` all values...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var balanceamount = parseFloat( $("#balance").val() );
        var actual_amount = parseFloat( $("#total_amount").val() );
        var total_balance = parseFloat( $("#totalbalance").val() );

        $("#amount").keyup(function ()
        {
            var amount = parseFloat( $("#amount").val() );
            var total_balance = parseFloat( $("#totalbalance").val() );
            var total_amount = total_balance + amount;
            alert(total_amount);
            $("#total_amount").val(total_amount.toFixed(2));

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. I think you should use `parseInt()` to convert the values to int. Also check is any field contains empty string or not to get correct sumation.

```
$("#amount").keyup(function () {
        var amount = $("#amount").val() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#amount").val());
        var total_balance = $("#totalbalance").val() == '' ? 0 : parseFloat($("#totalbalance").val());
        var total_amount = total_balance + amount;
        alert(total_amount);
        $("#total_amount").val(total_amount.toFixed(2));

    });
```

Comment: But it can contain decimal point, hence in my opinion... `parseFloat` should be used...

Comment: See that he is using `total_amount.toFixed(2)` which clearly indicates he wants to allow decimal point.

Comment: Check my answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761219/result-not-getting-in-to-the-field/37761305#37761305

Answer (score 1):

Input values are strings, so when you perform this:

```
     var total_amount = total_balance + amount;
```

... you are concatenating strings, and also the `toFixed` method is not defined for strings.

The fastest way to convert your input values to numbers is by using the unitary plus:

```
     var total_amount = +total_balance + +amount;
```

Note that you might want to validate your input. You could also use `number` type `input` tags:

```
 <input id="amount" type="number">
```

... then `value` will be numerical (if valid).